# How to assess whether two variable are independently correlated?

Tags: correlation

I have a data set with three variables: A, B, and C. There are correlations between A and B, B and C, and A and C. I'm trying to figure out whether the correlation of A and C is purely a product of the A-B and B-C correlations, or whether A and C are independently correlated.

I assume there's probably a name for what I'm trying to do, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The method is to test the correlation between $A$ and $C$ directly.  Since you're not doing that, could you please explain what you mean by "independently correlated" and what information about these variables you do have?

Comment: I have best fit equations relating each variable to each other (including A to C), each with  a certain amount of rms scatter. Given the amount of scatter in the A-B and B-C correlations, it should be possible (I think) to calculate how much scatter should be in the A-C correlation if the two are only correlated by reason of both being correlated to B. If the actual scatter in the A-C relation is significantly less than this, that would indicate a direct link between A and C.

Comment: Does this [Wikipedia age on partial correlation])https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation)  answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.